# Installing Magento

Tags: installation

When I entered `localhost/magento/setup` on my browser it gives me this error

> Fatal error: Declaration of Zend\Mvc\Controller\PluginManager::get($name, ?array $options = NULL) must be compatible with Zend\ServiceManager\AbstractPluginManager::get($name, $options = Array, $usePeeringServiceManagers = true) in C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\vendor\zendframework\zend-mvc\src\Controller\PluginManager.php on line 211

its my first time using Magento, so I don't have a clue, what should I do?

Comment: If you are using it on your local system can you replace the url to 127.0.0.1/magento/

Comment: the result is still the same, but thanks for suggesting it.

Comment: This error is coming because of the php version 7.2(I guess) in your system as Magento doesn't support it for now. I you downgrade the php version it should work.

Comment: This link should help you https://community.magento.com/t5/Installing-Magento-2/Fatal-Error-Installing-on-XXamp/m-p/83571#M3441

Comment: I guess Nasir Perwaiz is right, the safest option is to downgrade to php 7.0 (some external modules does not even support 7.1)